# "non unique" sequence by Id

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13, odoo-14

I'm wondering if possible to have a sequence by sale order id, I saw that you can set apart sequences by company, I'm wondering if you can go and make non unique sequences by id.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data noupdate="1">
        <!-- Sequence -->
        <record id="sale_team_number_id" model="ir.sequence">
            <field name="name">Team number</field>
            <field name="code">Team.number</field>
            <field name="padding">3</field>
            <field name="company_id" eval="True"/>
            <field name="sale_order_id" eval="True"/>
        </record>

    </data>
</odoo>

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
  if(vals.get('number', _('New')) == _('New')):
    vals['number'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('Team.number') or ('New')

  result = super(Team, self).create(vals)
  return result
```

I got this sequence but is unique among sales order, I just want to have non repeated sequences between sales orders, like SO1 can have 1,2,3,4 and so on and SO2 can also have 1,2,3,4 is it something possible to be doing with this approach?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is out of box and hard to track specific order sequence. In OCA, have alternative solution for this. The module name is `sale_order_revision`.

Reference link for that module:

- v13.0 https://github.com/OCA/sale-workflow/tree/13.0/sale_order_revision
- v14.0 https://github.com/OCA/sale-workflow/tree/14.0/sale_order_revision